# Accessing grouped items in arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, grouping

I'm new to Python and have a list of numbers. e.g.
`5,10,32,35,64,76,23,53...`.

and I've grouped them into fours (`5,10,32,35`, `64,76,23,53` etc..) using the code from [this post](http://countergram.com/python-group-iterator-list-function).

```
def group_iter(iterator, n=2, strict=False):
    """ Transforms a sequence of values into a sequence of n-tuples.
    e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4, ...] => [(1, 2), (3, 4), ...] (when n == 2)
    If strict, then it will raise ValueError if there is a group of fewer
    than n items at the end of the sequence. """
    accumulator = []
    for item in iterator:
        accumulator.append(item)
        if len(accumulator) == n: # tested as fast as separate counter
            yield tuple(accumulator)
            accumulator = [] # tested faster than accumulator[:] = []
            # and tested as fast as re-using one list object
    if strict and len(accumulator) != 0:
        raise ValueError("Leftover values")
```

How can I access the individual arrays so that I can perform functions on them. For example, I'd like to get the average of the first values of every group (e.g. `5 and 64` in my example numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the following tuple of tuples:

```
a=((5,10,32,35), (64,76,23,53))
```

To access the first element of each tuple, use a for-loop:

```
for i in a:
     print i[0]
```

To calculate average for the first values:

```
elements=[i[0] for i in a]

avg=sum(elements)/float(len(elements))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is `yield`ing a tuple of four numbers each time it's iterated. So, convert the whole thing to a list:

```
L = list(group_iter(your_list, n=4))
```

Then you'll have a list of tuples:

```
>>> L
[(5, 10, 32, 35), (64, 76, 23, 53), ...]
```

You can get the first item in each tuple this way:

```
firsts = [tup[0] for tup in L]
```

(There are other ways, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

You've created a tuple of tuples, or a list of tuples, or a list of lists, or a tuple of lists, or whatever...

You can access any element of any nested list directly:

```
toplist[x][y] # yields the yth element of the xth nested list
```

You can also access the nested structures by iterating over the top structure:

```
for list in lists:
    print list[y]
```

Comment: You're redefining `list`, which is a standard class name. Not recommended.

Comment: Yeah normally I avoid doing that, but the python syntax highlighting helps in examples.

Answer (score 1):

Might be overkill for your application but you should check out my library, pandas. Stuff like this is pretty simple with the GroupBy functionality:

http://pandas.sourceforge.net/groupby.html

To do the 4-at-a-time thing you would need to compute a bucketing array:

```
import numpy as np
bucket_size = 4
n = len(your_list)
buckets = np.arange(n) // bucket_size
```

Then it's as simple as:

```
data.groupby(buckets).mean()
```